# Is there a way to pass a &[T] to Fortran through FFI?

Tags: vb.net, rust, fortran, ffi

I am working with a very old, proprietary Fortran library in a university research position. We have a VB.net interface for this Fortran Library, but my project is to create an interface for the library in Rust.

I can't change the Fortran code at all, so changing the function to accept a pointer is out of the question.

The Fortran Function looks like this:

```
SUBROUTINE FD_TEMP_DIST(POWER, ARRAY, LENGTH, INIT_VALUEA, INIT_VALUEB, BOT_FLAG)
    IMPLICIT NONE
!   ARGUMENT DECLARATIONS:
!   ------NAME---------                 
    REAL(8) POWER
    INTEGER(4)    LENGTH 
    REAL(8) ARRAY(LENGTH)
    REAL(8) INIT_VALUEA
    REAL(8) INIT_VALUEB
    LOGICAL(4) FLAG
```

And the VB.net code looks like this

```vb
        Public Declare Auto Sub SUBNAME Lib "lib" _
            (ByRef POWER As Double, ByRef ARRAY As Double, ByRef LENGTH As Int32, ByRef INIT_VALUEA As Double, _
             ByRef INIT_VALUEB As Double, ByRef FLAG As Byte)
```

I tried to recreate the VB function in Rust.

```rust
use libloading::{library_filename, Library, Symbol};
use std::result::Result;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::BYTE;

pub fn fd_temp_dist(
    power: f64,
    mut array: Vec<f64>,
    length: i32,
    init_value_a: f64,
    init_value_b: f64,
    flag: bool,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let func: Symbol<
        unsafe extern "stdcall" fn(&f64, &mut [f64], &i32, &f64, &f64, &BYTE),
    >;
    unsafe {
        let library = Library::new(library_filename(MODULE))?;
        func = library.get(b"_FD_TEMP_DIST@24")?;
        Ok(func(
            &power,
            &mut array,
            &length,
            &init_value_a,
            &init_value_b,
            &{
                if flag {
                    1_u8
                } else {
                    0_u8
                }
            },
        ))
    }
}
```

However, when I run the function, it throws an error saying that the memory at LENGTH can't be accessed.

If it's length 121, the error reads `Access violation reading location 0x00000079` and at length 120, the error reads `Access violation reading location 0x00000078`.

I'm not quite sure what's going wrong here. I think not being able to read that final memory location must be due to 1-indexing in Fortran, but I genuinely have no clue what is going on under the hood here so I can't be sure.

Hopefully someone here can give me some more insight.

Comment: I don't know Rust, but `0x00000079` certainly is 121 in hexadecimal. Could it be a string termination or something?

Comment: Are `Int32` and `Byte` the same lengths as `integer(4)` and `logical(4)`? Recall that default integer and default logical in Fortran are the same storage size

Comment: Slices do not have a stable ABI, and you should not use them as an argument of an extern function. You should instead pass the pointer and length separately.

Comment: `LOGICAL(4)` probably corresponds to `Integer` not `Byte` in the VB (a common scheme is for the Fortran KIND to correspond to the bytes of storage that it takes up).  If `FLAG` is modified in the Fortran, very bad things *might* happen depending on memory layout.  If it isn't modified, you would probably get junk in part of the value, but it may still appear to work correctly.

Comment: _"changing the function to accept a pointer is out of the question"_ in fact your Fortran function already takes pointers. Passing simple references should work (e.g. `&i32` where an `i32*` is expected), but not for fat references (e.g. you can't pass a `&[f64]` where the Fortran function expects a `f64*`).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but it might solve problems for other users working in Fortran and VB.net.  It doesn't fix the rust problems.

1. VB arrays begin at 0 - DIM X(10) will have 11 items.  Filling in elements 1 to 10 of the VB array will appear as elements 2 to 11 in Fortran
2. If it is a single variable, pass BYREF.
3. If it is only a 1D array, pass the array **BYVAL**.  It doesn't matter whether it is IN, OUT or INOUT.  You just need to get the addressing right: don't worry about Fortran's semantics.
4. In VB, make sure the solution platform is either win32 or X64.  `Any CPU` does not know what type of DLL you are using and will default to whatever model it picks up when the program is started.
5. Use either the dependency checker, or `dumpbin /DEPENDENTS` on the DLL to work out what other DLLs are required by the generated DLL.  dumpbin is part of visual studio
6. Move the generated DLL and copy any of its dependencies to where the VB executable resides.  Don't rely on PATH - depending on where the directories are, it might pick up the wrong dll with the same name.
7. Use `dumpbin /EXPORTS` on the generated DLL to find out what the exported symbols are.  In the case of gfortran, there is a trailing underscore.  Some have leading underscores, some don't add anything.

The following has been tested with gfortran and VB.net

Fortran

```
      SUBROUTINE FD_TEMP_DIST(POWER, ARRAY, LENGTH, INIT_VALUEA, 
     &    INIT_VALUEB, FLAG)
      IMPLICIT NONE
!   ARGUMENT DECLARATIONS:
!   ------NAME---------                 
      REAL(8) POWER
      INTEGER(4)    LENGTH 
      REAL(8) ARRAY(*)
      REAL(8) INIT_VALUEA
      REAL(8) INIT_VALUEB
      LOGICAL(4) FLAG
      INTEGER II
      ! Dummy routine - just print what we got
      PRINT *, 'FTN POWER ', POWER
      PRINT '(A,20D10.2)', 'FTN ARRAY ', (ARRAY(ii), II = 1, LENGTH)
      PRINT *, 'FTN INITA ', INIT_VALUEA
      PRINT *, 'FTN INITB ', INIT_VALUEB
      PRINT *, 'FTN FLAG  ', FLAG
      ! Change contents of ARRAY
      DO II = 1, LENGTH
          ARRAY(II) = SQRT(II * 1.0)
      ENDDO
      END SUBROUTINE
```

After building the DLL, dumpbin /EXPORTS on the created by gfortran shows that the exported symbol is fd_temp_dist_ (lowercase!)

VB.net

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Module Module1

    <DllImport("flib.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint:="fd_temp_dist_")>
    Public Sub fd_temp_dis(
        ByRef power As Double,
        parray() As Double,
        ByRef length As Integer,
        ByRef inita As Double,
        ByRef initb As Double,
        ByRef flag As Boolean)
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim length As Integer
        Dim parray(10) As Double

       ' Print array before
        length = 10
        For ii = 0 To length - 1
            parray(ii) = length - ii
            Console.Write(" " & parray(ii))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()

        Call fd_temp_dis(123.0, parray, length, 456.0, 789.0, vbTrue)

        ' Print array after
        For ii = 0 To length - 1
            Console.Write(" " & parray(ii))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Building the Fortran using gfortran and msys

```
setlocal
rem add gfortran to the path
set msys=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin
@path %msys%;%path%

set where=ftest\bin\X64\debug

del %where%\flib.dll
gfortran flib.f -shared -o flib.dll
move flib.dll %where%

if not exist %where%\libgfortran-5.dll (
    copy %msys%\libgfortran-5.dll %where%
    copy %msys%\libquadmath-0.dll %where%
    copy %msys%\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll %where%
    copy %msys%\libwinpthread-1.dll %where%
)
endlocal
```